# Managing connected USB list with Flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, windows, macos, usb, libusb

In the software I developed with Flutter desktop, I want to listen to USB ports on Windows and Mac OS operating systems and send and receive byte-type data. Is there a method for this?

I tried the QuickUsb package and I get an error as follows.

`flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@66265524' has not been initialized. #0      QuickUsbPlatform._instance (package:quick_usb/src/quick_usb_platform_interface.dart) #1      QuickUsbPlatform.instance (package:quick_usb/src/quick_usb_platform_interface.dart:16:43) #2      _platform (package:quick_usb/quick_usb.dart:10:52) #3      QuickUsb.init (package:quick_usb/quick_usb.dart:13:33) #4      PrinterCubit.initialProcess (package:*_desktop/cubit/printer_cubit.dart:14:14) #5      new PrinterCubit (package:*_desktop/cubit/printer_cubit.dart:10:5) #6      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:*_desktop/main.dart:64:32) #7      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:736:36) #8      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:590:33) #9      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:303:37) #10     ReadContext.read (package:provider/src/provider.dart:649:21) #11     _BlocListenerBaseState.initState (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_listener.dart:143:36) #12     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5611:55) #13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5) #14     SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11) #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16) #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18) #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16) #18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7) #19     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5) #20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5) #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16) #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18) #735    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7) #736    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5) #737    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5) #738    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16) #739    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18) #740    _RawViewElement._updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/view.dart:291:16) #741    _RawViewElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/view.dart:314:5) #742    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16) #743    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18) #744    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16) #745    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7) #746    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5) #747    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5) #748    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16) #749    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18) #750    RootElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1354:16) #751    RootElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1323:5) #752    RootWidget.attach.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1276:18) #753    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2844:19) #754    RootWidget.attach (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1275:13) #755    WidgetsBinding.attachToBuildOwner (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1088:27) #756    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1070:5) #757    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1056:7) #758    Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15) #759    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19) #760    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5) #761    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.